# How to trigger watch hook in VueJS 3

Tags: vue.js, vuex, watch

I am working on a VueJS application where I want to watch for a change in the state of a user from the vuex store and do something. The changes are happening but the watch hook is not being triggered.

This is the code of the computed property and the watch.

```
computed: {
    formIsValid() {
      return (
        this.form.company &&
        this.form.street &&
        this.form.phone &&
        this.form.selectedRole &&
        this.form.selectedStatus &&
        this.form.email &&
        this.form.industry &&
        this.form.password
      );
    },
    user() {
      this.$store.getters.getUser;
      console.log("Computed" + this.$store.getters.getUser.id);
    }
  },

  watch: {
    user(value) {
      console.log("A change has occured");
      console.log({ user: value });
      if (value !== null && value !== undefined) {
        console.log("ama is going");
        this.$router.push({ name: "Jobs" });
      } else {
        console.log("The thing is null");
      }
    }
  },
```

Comment: "_watch hook in VueJS 3_" There is no `watch` in vue composition API, we do have `watchEffect` though.

Answer (score 1):

In your `user` computed method, you're not `return`-ing a value. I suspect if you look in Vue devtools, computed: user has a value of `undefined`.

I believe your change should be...

```
computed: {
  user() {
    console.log("Computed" + this.$store.getters.getUser.id);
    return this.$store.getters.getUser;
  }
}
```